# Site returning blank page after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, web-deployment, webdeploy

I'm working on a mvc site which is working fine at local, but when I deploy it on the server, a specific page doesn't work (all the other pages are working perfectly)..it's returning a blank page, with Status Code 200 ok. I'm deploying the site using a publish profile from Visual studio and web deploy.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: what does the page do? does the page really get the data from database you are connecting to in the deployed environment?

Comment: The page should display a Kendo grid. No, it doesn't get the data from the db, it show a request with the URL for my page and in the Response tab (I'm using Chrome dev tools to look at the request 
details) says "Failed to load response data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself, posting the answer in case someone else has the same problem.
I just put a try catch in my controller (in the action method that should redirect to my view) and in the catch block I wrote this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        }
```

to be able to see the exception message in the browser.